# How to display some data in SSRS 2005

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

I want to display some data in Reporting Services (SSRS 2005) like this:

> ```
>        Month 1    Month 2 Month 3  ...
> ```
>
> Employee
>     Smith
>     GrossSales    20 $                15 $          20 $
>     Green
>     GrossSales  50 $                  25 $           20 $
>  ...

I want to use table and/or matrix, but how? I get the data
from an MDX-query which returns Name, Month and GrossSales.

Also, the row and column names should not be visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Matrix is definitely the way forward for this one.  It shouldn't matter that it's an MDX resultset.

If you set the column group as the month column and Employee on the row group you'll get exactly the result you're after.  You can then put Gross Sales into the cell and it will sum it up.